# Help finding exponential and linear growth?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I need help finding the equations for two problems.

1. Salary of $\$100,000$ increasing by $\$10,000$ each year for $5$ years.
2. Salary of $\$75,000$ increasing by $30\%$ each year for $5$ years.

I know that one will be an exponential equation and one will be a linear equation. I also know that for the salary **increasing by $\$10,000$ each year** the sums are:

Year 1: 100,000
2: 110,000
3: 120,000
4: 130,000
5: 140,000

and for the salary **increasing by 30% each year** the sums are:

year 1: 75,000
2: 97,500
3: 126,750
4: 164,775
5: 240,825

I believe the salary increasing by 10,000 each year might be: 100,000 + (100,000*.10t), because it increases by 10% of the initial 100,000 each year (t), but I'm not sure.

Thank you!

Comment: Try making a table for both problems, and draw graphs, and continue from there. Try also rereading section on first differences, 2nd differences and ratios to test for linearity, quadratic, exponentials.

Answer (score 2):

So, in the first case, you have
\begin{equation}
y(t)=100,000+(10,000\cdot t)
\end{equation}
The variable $t$ is multypling a constant and the function $y(t)$ is a polynomial, which means that $y(t)$ is a linear function, and is linear in $t$.

For the second question, consider that:
\begin{equation}
y_2=y_1+0.3\cdot y_1= 1.3 \cdot y_1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y_3= 1.3 \cdot y_2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\vdots
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y_t= 1.3 \cdot y_{t-1}
\end{equation}
Which, substituting in a single expression, gives: 
\begin{equation}
y_t=(1.3)^t \cdot y_1
\end{equation}
that is if you take as $t=0$ as your starting point at $y_1=75,000$. If your starting point is $t=1$, then you simply have: 
\begin{equation}
y(t)=(1.3)^{(t-1)} \cdot y_1
\end{equation}
This equation has the variable as the exponent of a constant, hence the linearity is violated and the function is said to be exponential in $t$.
And by the way check yours calculations, the amounts per year are:
\begin{equation}
y_1=$75,000\\
y_2=$97,500\\
y_3=$126,750\\
y_4=$164,775\\
y_5=$214,2075\\
\end{equation}

These are the plots:
[Plot 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3D100000%2B(10000*%20t)%20from%200%20to%205)
[Plot 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3D75000*1.3%5Ex%20from%200%20to%205)